# Screen Sharing in iOS using opentok

Tags: ios, swift, opentok, tokbox, screensharing

Hello i am using opentok for screen sharing.Everything is working fine but one issue is i am facing it works correctly in iOS simulator mean screen is sharing perfectly but in real iOS device screen is not sharing black screen is appearing on other device.

Answer (score 0):

When using screen sharing you can share the contents of a given UIView inside your application. Due to iOS security restrictions you cannot share the content of any other view outside your application. (If you send your application to the background the other end will receive a black screen since the view you are sharing is not longer being rendered)

Please take a look to the screen sharing sample for more details: https://github.com/opentok/opentok-ios-sdk-samples-swift/tree/master/Screen-Sharing

Comment: yes i know ,i am sharing current view , still getting black screen

Comment: Have you tried the sample code of the link?, Did it work on a real device?

Comment: yes i have run that code, same issue in real device.

Comment: Just ran the sample code in an iPhone 6 and it works ok. I can see the opentok screen with the date time string on it. I'm afraid that there is something wrong on your end.

Comment: @ArxlanAli Did you resolved this issue? I am having the same problem. Please help

Comment: @Lena yes i resolved this issue. my issue was api token ,session key that my server was generating.There are some settings in server side to create this tokens.
Check you backend language that is generating session tokens etc

Comment: @ArxlanAli thanks for the replay. we found out that the issue was with publisher